# Is app-crypt/gnupg on Portage or overlays?

Tags: gentoo, gpg

I want to use multiple pgp key servers with the [sks key server group](https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php) witch imply `gnupg-curl` installation for the hkps protocol.

But I didn’t find `gnupg-curl` as an ebuild in Portage or, at least, as a USE flag of `app-crypt/gnupg`.

So what is the best solution? Using an overlay or compile it by myself?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: To install a package witch caled [`gnupg-curl`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gnupg-curl) by debian.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent. `gnupg-curl` is only relevant to the old, 1.x branch of GnuPG, and is irrelevant for GPG 2.0 (stable, default on gentoo) and 2.1 (modern). You can use multiple keyservers without any extra effort.